# How to handle string localisation in jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, localization

I am making an android app using phonegap and jQuery mobile.The app will also have option for displaying text in other languages like Tamil,Kannada and Telugu.I want to change all the text displayed when the user clicks on these options for changing the language. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878002/phonegap-internationalization-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at [i18next](http://jamuhl.github.com/i18next/), a JS library that runs entirely in browser and whose localizations are stored in JSON. It works with jQuery and has several other nice features. Seems like it would cover your needs.

Comment: But i18 doesn't support indian languages like Tamil. How do I handle that?

Comment: Have you tried defining a new language code for Tamil? Maybe it "just works"?

Comment: i18next is OK however if you have a lot of dynamic stuff that is third party, you can't add the data-i18n attributes, so you have to go thru CSS selectors. I had to go custom in all projects that I have worked thus far. The way it works is similar to i18next however you don't have to tag the application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running a Application which supports around 5 European languages. I manually created a language file in the format of `JSON`. I wrote custom functions to replace the UI element's labels in a separate file which triggers when a page loads.

It just works fine for me.

Comment: Plus one. I had to do the same, create dictionary files and replace UI elements i18 is still lacking in jQuery Mobile. But they they prefer to make things pretty instead of focusing in creating something that is usable.

Answer (score 0):

check out the HTMLed.js framework for jquery mobile localization on GitHub [link](https://nirus.github.com/HTMLed)