# what is the best way to localize an mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, mobile-application

I just want to know which way is the best between

1.building for each language the same app or 
2.using localization for the same app.

I work with phonegap and for it there are ways using javascript to make the app localized but I wonder about the size of the app(apple store limit the size and it is also not good the app to have a big size because of localization)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap/Cordova internationalization support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878002/phonegap-cordova-internationalization-support)

Answer (score 2):

It surely is the 2nd way. No matter what platform you are working with, this is the only purpose of localization. To translate user visible texts, with no need to regenerate the whole code behind. Just think of how big part of your application are these text in comparison of the rest of your app (if you are not providing some kind of eBook, application part will be more then 90%) so this way is much more efficient. 
And from all, it is almost unsustainable to make changes and updates (even very small) in big number of localized applications.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use the same app for different localizations. It will be much easier to maintain, market and distribute. Also, assuming your image files don't contain text (which they normally shouldn't) and all (or at the very least most) of your text is actually text (and not images of text), you shouldn't fear the file size impact of this too much, as your localized text files will probably be an insignificant addition to the overall file size.

Most importantly, Apple will probably **NOT** approve multiple versions of the same app in different languages (they usually approve the first one or two duplicates, but once you try to submit another, they say that you're spamming the app store and should combine the apps into one localized app). And they have a point there...