# How to translate whole application into hindi phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, translation

Can anyone tell me, how can I convert my phonegap application from English language to hindi language.

I have a tab of Settings option for language settings in App.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova is just a framework to show web pages in an native-app and using some plugin to interact with the device hardware . The support of internationalization/localization is completely dependent on your application design.

One probable approach to resolve this issue it to have language specific HTMLs in respective language folders and invoke the same based on language settings. Another approach would be to have language specific json created and make use of the same in HTML files based on language settings.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878002/phonegap-cordova-internationalization-support) should help you out.

Answer (score -1):

Consider Phonegap as HTML/JS Framework. If your html open in hindi language in your browser then it will works in phonegap.

Comment: Question says app is in English.and questioner wants to give functionality to user to switch between languages.